# How to convert below code in magento2 standard way

Tags: magento2.4

what is equivalent in m2.If we want to convert below code in magento2 which class we can use to send json response directly from helper class.

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->clearHeaders()
                    ->setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
                    ->setBody($jsonContent)->sendResponse();                   
                    exit;
```

Comment: Use "Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json" for return.

Answer (score 0):

**Class :- Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;**

```
$resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$resultJson->setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
$resultJson->setBody($jsonContent);
$resultJson->sendResponse();
```

Comment: getting error `Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json\Interceptor::setBody()`

Answer (score 0):

Within a controller try

Using an array

```
$jsonArray = []

/** \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory **/
$resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$resultJson->setJsonData($jsonArray);
return $resultJson;
```

Using raw JSON content

```
/** \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory **/
$result = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
$result->setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
$result->setContents($jsonContent);
return $result;
```